# Creating a dictionary from a set of dictionary: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror

```
status = [
{'id':'1', 'name': 'US'},
{'id':'2', 'name': 'UK'},
{'id':'3', 'name': 'India'},
{'id':'4', 'name': 'Mumbai'},
{'id':'5', 'name': 'NewYork'}
]
```

I have this `list` `status` of the dictionaries as I mentioned above. I wish to create my own dictionary such as

```
my_dict = 
{
     'myWorld' : {'id':'1', 'name': 'US'},
    {'id':'2', 'name': 'UK'},
    {'id':'3', 'name': 'India'},
    {'id':'4', 'name': 'Mumbai'},
    {'id':'5', 'name': 'NewYork'}
}
```

So to generate `my_dict` with `key` as `myWorld` and whole `status` as `dictionary values`, I did:

```
my_dict = dict((each["myWorld"], each) for each in status)
```

Is it the correct approach of handling this case??
I got error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Where it's going wrong? and what should I do to solve this?
I think some function must be there to do this.

Comment: The statuses don't have a `myWorld` key ... It's unclear what you're trying to do here, but the error is pretty obvious.  You're trying to use a list as a key in the dictionary.  `list` aren't hashible (which is a requirement for dict keys), so an exception is thrown.

Comment: Your `my_dict` definition only has a key for the first value. The rest are just values which will give a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: I want to make one new dictionary of all the dictionaries I'm having. So all those dictionaries (currently they are list `status` in my program ), will be the `values` of my new dictionary `my_dict` and I want to assign a key `myWorld` to it.

Comment: a dict key can only have one value unless you put the values in some container

Comment: How do you expect to access, say, the value `'Mumbai'` in your new `my_dict` data structure?

Comment: All keys in a dict must be distinct, so if you have several values, you need several keys all distinct

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pprint import pprint
status = [
{'id':'1', 'name': 'US'},
{'id':'2', 'name': 'UK'},
{'id':'3', 'name': 'India'},
{'id':'4', 'name': 'Mumbai'},
{'id':'5', 'name': 'NewYork'}
]

def make_dict(key, values):
    return {key: values}

pprint(make_dict("My_world", status))
```

result:

```
{'My_world': [{'id': '1', 'name': 'US'},
              {'id': '2', 'name': 'UK'},
              {'id': '3', 'name': 'India'},
              {'id': '4', 'name': 'Mumbai'},
              {'id': '5', 'name': 'NewYork'}]}
```

Comment: `my_dict = 
{
     'myWorld' : {'id':'1', 'name': 'US'},
    {'id':'2', 'name': 'UK'},
    {'id':'3', 'name': 'India'},
    {'id':'4', 'name': 'Mumbai'},
    {'id':'5', 'name': 'NewYork'}
}`

I tried the way you mentioned above but It gives `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: in your code, you try to make a dictionary, where first pair key/value  is "MyWorld" and {'id':'1'...}, and second if keyless, only value.  
paste the code where you get 'dict' object is not callable